# How to update table without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I need to  better way to update the table due to performance issue This is my current table structure Now based on the weekNum, Table 2 value need to updated. Currently using pivot to get update, any other alternate solution. Please help

**Table1:**

```
╔════════╦══════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ Row ID ║ Desc ║ WeekNum║  Amt  ║
╠════════╬══════╬════════╬═══════╣
║      1 ║ Total║     01 ║ 25.00 ║
║      2 ║ Total║     02 ║ 55.00 ║
║      3 ║ Total║     04 ║ 78.00 ║
║      4 ║ Total║     06 ║ 99.00 ║
║      5 ║ Total║     07 ║ 54.00 ║
║      6 ║ Total║     09 ║ 58.00 ║
╚════════╩══════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

**Table2:**

```
 ╔══╦═════╦══════╦══════╗═════╗═══════╗══════╗══════╗══════╗═════╗══════╗
 ║ID║ Desc║  01  ║  02  ║ 03  ║   04  ║  05  ║ 06   ║ 07   ║ 08  ║ 09   ║
 ╠══╬═════╬══════╬══════╣═════║═══════║══════║══════║══════║═════║═════ ║ 
 ║ 1║Total║25.00 ║55.00 ║NULL ║ 78.00 ║ NULL ║ 99.00║54.00 ║NULL ║58.00 ║
 ╚══╩═════╩══════╩══════╝═════╝═══════╝══════╝══════╝══════╝═════╝══════╝
```

Comment: Why do you need/want the table 2 format?  It is hard to generate and will scale very badly as you add more columns.

Comment: Add your current way of updating. That will avoid people suggesting same approach.

Comment: Now you understand why normalisation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is important. If you change your table layout of table 2 to (ID, Desc, Weekno), your problem vanishes immediately

Comment: if I change the table2 to (ID, Desc,Weekno) it will cause a big mess(impact) on application side, other than changing the table structure any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If the `PIVOT` is slow, you can separate it to `9` different updates wrapped in transaction. Your base query will be:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [01] = T2.[Amnt]
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.[Desc] = T2.[Desc]
WHERE T2.[Week] = '01';
```

You will do this for each column. If your real example contains bigger number of distinct, weeks, you can use dynamic T-SQL statement to build the execution code. It will be shorter and looks better. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @DistitincWeeks TABLE
(
    [Week] VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO @DistitincWeeks ([Week])
SELECT DISTINCT [Week]
FROM Table1;

DECLARE @DynamictSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@CurrentWeek VARCHAR(8);

WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @DistitincWeeks))
BEGIN;
    SELECT TOP (1) @CurrentWeek = [Week]
    FROM @DistitincWeeks;
    --

    SET @DynamictSQLStatement = @DynamictSQLStatement + 
    '
    UPDATE Table1
    SET [' + @CurrentWeek + '] = T2.[Amnt]
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2
        ON T1.[Desc] = T2.[Desc]
    WHERE T2.[Week] = ''' +  @CurrentWeek  +''';    
    ';

    --
    DELETE FROM @DistitincWeeks
    WHERE [Week] @CurrentWeek 
END;

EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamictSQLStatement;
```

Alternatively, you can create an after insert trigger on the `Table1` which modifies the corresponding rows in `Table2` when data is changed. You can use variant of the code above for the trigger body. Just be sure you are manipulating the rows in batches, not in loop or using cursor.

I don't like triggers and will advice if you have a routine, stored procedure or other application code, which is updating the `Table1` data, just do update the data in the `Table2`, too. It's more clear for me, but you must be sure no other routine is modifying the data in `Table1`.

It will be better to constantly updating `Table2` on small batches, when data in `Table1` is modified against performing huge updates on every X hours or days.

If the following update is slow, too:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET [01] = T2.[Amnt]
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2
    ON T1.[Desc] = T2.[Desc]
WHERE T2.[Week] = '01';
```

You should check the table structure (column types) itself and the corresponding indexes.